# what is the date format of "22:40:29.668 EET Sun Jan 02 2011" in java?

Tags: java, date-format

what is the date format of "22:40:29.668 EET Sun Jan 02 2011" in java. what i nedded is to know the format of this date ex. format of 12/12/2011 is dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: "ex. format of 12/12/2011 is dd/mm/yyyy" - No, that's wrong; the format of that is `dd/MM/yyyy`. Note that the case is important; `mm` means minutes, `MM` means months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chart on the [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc.

[image]

You should be able to find the pattern according to this chart.

`new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);`

Comment: The table is for US locale only. From javadoc: `The following examples show how date and time patterns are interpreted in the U.S. locale...`. Although, he is asking for english date pattern, but for completeness sake you can mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

your question is ambigious, 12/12/2011 could be either mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy...

but i would suggest using the reverse date library in java (it's a third party tool)

Comment: That was just a side remark, but does really deserve the downpoint as I tried to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Format of the sample is neither dd/mm/yy/ nor mm/dd/yy, it's M dd YYYY or something like this.